# Spring WebFlux/ Reactor core

Tags: reactive-programming, spring-webflux

I am using Spring WebFlux , reactor core . I have a doubt. Does Spring webflux follow thread-per-request model? What I mean to ask is - Is there a possibility in spring webflux that a single request can be executed my multiple TOMCAT threads?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, the blocking I/O parts of the Servlet spec enforce a one thread per request model.

But non-blocking servers and even the Servlet 3.1 async I/O spec aren't enforcing that. In the case of Tomcat, the server is starting with a few threads to support both uses cases, but in WebFlux a request served by Tomcat might be processed by one or more Tomcat threads.

[See the Spring Framework reference documentation "Concurrency model" section for more information about that.](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web-reactive.html#webflux-concurrency-model)

Comment: Thanks for your reply , Brian. If this is the case, then how does a single request's context ( or state ) get shared between multiple tomcat threads? In thread-per-request model, context of request is limited to that executing thread only. In spring webflux, let's say Tomcat-thread-1 started executing  request-1 and did some operations and went onto other request-2 without completing request-1. Now let's say Tomcat-thread-2 picks request-1 and start executing it. So, How does thread-2 get access to request-1's state , i.e, variable values, stack, etc. ?

Comment: each server has its own model variant for that. Some are using "event loops" or "reactor patterns". They basically dispatch events (units of work) to a predefined number of worker threads - one request being possibly several units of work (reading and writing data). In general Threads can share data, it's just getting a problem in case of concurrent access.

Comment: I am sorry but I didn't get your last statement : "Threads can share data, it's just getting a problem in case of concurrent access." . Can you please elaborate?